# AngularJS provider not working as per styleguide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following [John Papa's Angular1 styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and trying to implement a provider.

The provider as per the document looks like this,

```
angular
    .module('blocks.router')
    .provider('routerHelper', routerHelperProvider);

routerHelperProvider.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
/* @ngInject */
function routerHelperProvider($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    this.$get = RouterHelper;

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    RouterHelper.$inject = ['$state'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function RouterHelper($state) {
        var hasOtherwise = false;

        var service = {
            configureStates: configureStates,
            getStates: getStates
        };

        return service;

        ///////////////

        function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
            states.forEach(function(state) {
                $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
            });
            if (otherwisePath && !hasOtherwise) {
                hasOtherwise = true;
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(otherwisePath);
            }
        }

        function getStates() { return $state.get(); }
    }
}
```

I've mocked up a very basic version [here on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BLJrt8scj8h4LrGvPwdC?p=preview)

**My provider:**

```
angular
  .module('plunker')
  .provider('random', function() {
    this.$get = helper;
    this.getX = function() {
      return 10;
    }

    function helper() {
      var provider = {
        getX: getX,
        getY: getY
      }

      return provider;

      function getX() {
        return 10;
      }

      function getY() {
        return 20;
      }
    }
  });
```

So, `getX` works fine, but `getY` is undefined.

Fear, I'm missing something very trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a getter for getX but not for getY:

```
this.getX = function() {
  return 10;
}

this.getY = function() {
  return 20;
}
```

Here is a forked version of your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lHBj6LiirisZ4Bb6DM9M?p=preview

Comment: that's not what the styleguide says?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be adding `getY` method too?

```
angular
  .module('plunker')
  .provider('random', function() {
    this.$get = helper;
    this.getX = function() {
      return 10;
    }
    this.getY = function() {
        return 10;
    }

    function helper() {
      var provider = {
        getX: getX,
        getY: getY
      }

      return provider;
      // not required after return statement, why you need them?
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, but that's not how the structure is as per the styleguide.